# how can i get the number of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple input fields and each input contains comma separated values

```
<input type="text" class="form-control tags tokenfield" name="variant[value]" value="red,blue,green">
```

I have a lot of tags input class and each input contains a variable number of `tags`. How can I loop over the inputs and get the total number of tags that I have using jQuery?

```
$('.tags').on('change', function(event){
    for(i = 0; i < $('.tags').length; i++){
        // Stuck here - not sure what to do
    }
});
```

How can i create a table of options based on this elements like that : 
[image]

Comment: To clarify: are you calling the comma separated `value` string as "tags"? That is, are `red`, `blue`, and `green` "tags"?

Comment: You want to collect the values separated by the commas so if there's 3 items in input that's three values?

Comment: unclear, be more precise , count number of values separated by comma, number of differents values separated by  comma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you loop over each input's value, use the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split the string at the commas and count the number of items in the resulting array:

```js
$('.tags').on('change', function(event){
  $('.tags').each(function(index, element){
    console.log("Input " + (index + 1) + " has " + element.value.split(",").length + " items in it.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control tags tokenfield" name="variant[value]" value="red,blue,green">
<input type="text" class="form-control tags tokenfield" name="variant[value]" value="red,blue,green,yellow">
<input type="text" class="form-control tags tokenfield" name="variant[value]" value="red,blue,green,orange, brown">
<input type="text" class="form-control tags tokenfield" name="variant[value]" value="red,blue">
```

Comment: thank you so much, please i have updated my question, i would like to create a table based on the elements, can you double check please

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi You're welcome. My answer above answers the first question that you've asked. If you agree, please mark it as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer. Then, instead of editing your question to ask another (which is a no-no, only ask one question at a time), post a new question. And, when you do post a question, don't just ask "How do I do this?", we expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt at a solution before posting. Then, if you get stuck, you can ask a ***specific*** question about what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the `.val()` of `.each()` `$('.tag')` and `.split()` the values at each comma. Each input will add an array of values which can be one single array using `.flat()`. To get the total number use `.length`

```js
var tags = [];
$('.tag').each(function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  var arr = str.split(',');
  tags.push(arr);
});
var tagValues = tags.flat();
console.log(JSON.stringify(tagValues));
console.log("Total number: "+tagValues.length)
```

```html
<input class='tag' value='1,2,3'>
<input class='tag' value='red,blue,yellow'> 
<input class='tag' value='Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```